# Is it possible to insert a random value into a range in php?

Tags: php, html, range

What I'm interested in doing is creating a range of numeral values for an html drop down menu, ranging from 18 to 75. My client is asking that between the numbers 29 and 30, I interrupt the range with the value 'Choose', which would be the default option.

I don't see this as necessary, but I thought I'd play around and see if it's even possible. The range is already created, so now I've got to find a way to reliably insert 'Choose' into the middle of it. I've tried a few things based on google searches and comments in the function's manual, so now I'm turning to stack. Thanks for any advice!

edit:  Here is the code...

```
<?php
$age = range(18, 75);
echo ( '<select class="dropdown nextPanel" name="age">' );
    foreach ($age as $option){
        echo ( "<option value='".$option."'>".$option."</option>" );
    }
echo ( '</select>' );
?>
```

Another edit: Crap, I suppose I'm trying to interrupt a foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've got the range (using `range(18, 75)`?) and want to insert `Choose` between 29 and 30?

```
$pos = array_search(29, $range); // returns the index of 29
array_splice($range, $pos+1, 0, array('Choose'));
```

That will insert 'Choose' right after the value `29` in `$range`.

If you want to do it only when it's being printed, you can look at ehudokai's answer for a start.

**EDIT**: If all you want to do is insert the 'Choose' option after option number 29, and set it as the default option in a select:

```
foreach($range as $v) {
    if($v == 30) {
        echo "<option value='choose' selected='selected'>Choose</option>";
    }
    echo "<option value='$v'>$v</option>";
}
```

This way it will still print out the regular options, but when it encounters option `30`, it will first print out the default `choose` option, and mark it as selected.

Comment: I've managed to insert Choose in the range without issues, but that still doesn't allow me to set it as the default option. I've tried ehudokai's answer as well (Seemed like an obvious solution once I saw it) but I haven't had any luck with it. I feel like I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Ahhh I apologize. I realize now that I asked my question wrong. You answered properly - What I'm really doing is trying to add something to a foreach function. Your answer is essentially right based on how I phrased my question.

Comment: @Steve: See my updated answer for a working example for what you're trying to do, specifically.

Comment: Perfect! That does it. Thanks a lot Alex!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't `array_splice` work?

```
 $myarr = range( $start, $end );
 array_splice( $myarr, round( count( $myarr ) / 2 ), 0, 'Choose');
```

Comment: @RobertPitt It's closer to an answer, especially with the code included.

Comment: I played with this a bit earlier but it doesn't allow setting 'Choose' as the default. There must be a more efficient method. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($rangevalue == 29){
    echo "<input value=\"\" selected>Choose</input>";
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, but at a glance it seemed like a great idea. Perhaps I'm implementing it wrong... I'll try a few more things. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll get back to you if I can get it to work.